# Are there binomials of degree $n$ that can be factored into more than $O(\log n)$ distinct factors?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm searching for binomials $x^n \pm y$ that can be factored into many distinct factors. The best I currently have are binomials of the form $x^{2^k} - y^{2^k}$, which can be factored into $k + 1$ binomials by repeated application of the identity $a^2 - b^2 = (a + b) (a - b)$. As an example, $x^4 - y^4 = (x^2 + y^2)(x^2 - y^2) = (x^2 + y^2)(x + y)(x - y)$. My question is: Can we do better than $O(\log n)$ factors, where $n$ is the exponent of $x$? I also looked at the sum / difference of cubes formula, but it seems that we also end up with $O(\log n)$ factors by repeated application of this one.

Comment: All such binomials can be completely factored over the complex numbers - its the fundamental theorem of algebra. But maybe you’re after certain kinds of factors? Or solutions over the integers? Maybe you could clarify

Comment: I'm only looking for factors over the integers. But the factors do not have to be of degree 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The irreducible factorization of $x^n - 1$ over $\mathbb{Z}$ is known exactly; it is given by

$$x^n - 1 = \prod_{d \mid n} \Phi_d(x)$$

where $\Phi_d(x)$ are the [cyclotomic polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial). This gives a corresponding factorization of $x^n - y^n$ via homogenization (substituting $\frac{x}{y}$ and then multiplying by $y^n$).

This means the number of factors is $d(n)$, the [divisor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function) of $n$. We can do better than $O(\log n)$ by taking $n$ to have many distinct prime factors. For example if we take $n = \prod_{i=1}^k p_i$ to be the product of the first $k$ primes (the [primorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial)) then $n$ is roughly $e^{k \log k}$ and $d(n) = 2^k$, which is roughly something like $e^{\frac{\log n}{\log \log n}}$. You can see more information about the growth rate of $d(n)$ on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function#Growth_rate).